# CPU suddenly been used up a lot

Tags: laptop, cpu

I have a Dell XPS 14 (L1401X, core i7, Nvidia GT425M, 4GB RAM), which had been used for over a year now. Recently I installed a new RAM, Kingston 4GB 1333mHz DDR3, meaning I now have 8GB of RAM in total. I updated my Nvidia graphics driver and everything went just fine (fast, smooth gaming).

Two days later, I put my laptop on sleep, came back after four hours, started browsing Facebook using Google Chrome, and noticed the fan start getting noisy (which means the processor was running fast). I checked the task manager, the processor usage went up to 50%+. for only a glimpse of time then it went back to normal (1–4%). When I started playing hitman:absolution, everything became laggy and I was forced to terminate the program from the task manager. (This had never happened in the two days prior.)

I used CCleaner and Avira to clean the registry and check for viruses etc., but they reported back nothing. Everything had been fine two days before that and suddenly all these problems. How could this be happening?

Comment: what is the process that is jumping up in usage? Is it like this after a reboot? Or after being used for a long time?

Comment: I not sure, as I mentioned on top, whenever I check the task manager, the cpu usage dropped back to normal (2-5%), yes I have rebooted my laptop and the problem still persist.

Comment: without more info it could be alot of things. Turn your AntiVirus app off completely. Check your hdd for fragmentation, pagefile.... use AutoRuns & Process Explorer to check for applications that start on bootup: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: hmmm, now things were getting really weird, when I closed the task manager, everything went normal ( the processor didn't use much usage) but when I close it, the problems exist again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens when a new RAM is installed.

You have optimized the CPU performance. So, now just reinstall Windows. CPU performance will be fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What causes this issue when new RAM is installed?